# Some apps not supported on Samsung Galaxy Player

Tags: samsung-galaxy-player

I've never really used an Android device before about a week ago so I'm not terribly familiar with how this all works, but I've noticed that there are a couple of apps that I am not able to download on my Samsung Galaxy player, but my friends who have Android phones are able to. Any ideas on why this might be or how I could work around it. An example is Go Launcher Ex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developers can choose to target specific devices or not.  Presumably these apps are either limited to devices that are known to work, or have blacklisted the Galaxy Player due to incompatibility.

Another option is that some apps might be available only while connected to a cell network or a particular cell network.  There are some AT&T apps that are only available to those on AT&T, for example, and I imagine this might be more broadly the case.

Here are some workarounds:

1. Get the app via another (legitimate) means, possibly the developer's site or another app market.
2. Use an app like [MarketEnabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler) (requires root) to fake a different network.
3. Edit your `/system/build.prop` file to report your device as a different device.  Only edit the device name and versions and so on, not other settings, or your device may stop working!  You should be able to Google the various fields for other devices and see what to use if you want to mimic one.

<sub>Note that doing 2 or 3 in order to circumvent distribution controls may not be legal in your region.  The onus is on you to ensure you are acting legally.  I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. Etc.</sub>